# Get error when installing Comodo Antivirus

Tags: software-installation

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb  
Selecting previously unselected package cav-linux.
(Reading database ... 333566 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking cav-linux (from cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cav-linux:
 cav-linux depends on libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1); however:
  Package libssl0.9.8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing cav-linux (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cav-linux
```

Comment: I'd go with the second. A quick `sudo apt-get -f install` should get you right back on track.

Comment: @Oli mark this question as offtopic.See the op's comment inmy answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the `.deb` file via `gdebi` inorder to overcome dependency errors.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi /path/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: root@Kali:~/Desktop# sudo gdebi /path/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
gdebi error, file not found: /path/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
root@Kali:~/Desktop# sudo gdebi cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1)